# How to split by special character "\" in Lua?

Tags: lua, escaping, backslash

I tried to split by "\", but this character is so special in Lua, even if I use escape character "%", the IDE shows an error `Unterminated String constant`

```
local index = string.find("lua. is \wonderful", "%\", 1)
```

Comment: `string.find([[lua. is \wonderful]], [[\]], 1)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff When the first param is a variable, how to deal with that? I tried this, but It doesn't work. `local original = '\x00\x00\x01f\xd3d\x80X'
local index = string.find([[original]], [[\]], 1)`

Comment: `string.find(original, [[\]], 1)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You are right, I tried it before, but I got `nil`. Now I realized that programming language won't treat such string `'\x00\x00\x01f\xd3d\x80X'` as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert backslash `\` into a quoted string, escape it with itself: `"\\"`. `\` is [the escape character](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1) in regular quoted strings, so it is escaped with `\`. Or you can use the long string syntax, which doesn't allow escape sequences, as already pointed out: `[[\]]`.

Percent is only an escape character in a string that is being used as a [pattern](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1), so it is used before the magical characters `^$()%.[]*+-?` in the second argument to `string.find`, `string.match`, `string.gmatch`, and `string.gsub`, and `%%` represents `%` in the third argument to `string.gsub`.

The percent is still there in the string that is stored in memory, but backslash escape sequences are replaced with the corresponding character. `\\` becomes `\` when the string is stored in memory, and if you count the number of backslashes in a string `"\\"` using `string.gsub`, it will only find one: `select(2, string.gsub("\\", "\\", ""))` returns `1`.